How important is it to use publically available data in publication?
I have access a lot of data from hospitals and we as a team have been publishing works on application of AI models using the data.
recently, in one of the reviewers comments, the reviewer was addressing to use publically availabel data to showcase the improvements of our methods.
usually in health care setup, not many samples are avaialable publically. To address this comment, We will have to work on preprocessing of publically available data which might take months to do that.
How can i politely deny working with publically available data?
Thanks...

Welcome to the site and please consider taking the tour. Your title does not answer your question, "How can i politely deny working with publically available data?" Please clarify. Also, medical statistics deal with this problem on a regular basis, see https://www.harvardonline.harvard.edu/blog/anonymity-de-identification-accuracy-data and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4707567/ as examples. I suggest consulting with a local medical statistician to know the policies and norms of your institution and country.

An interesting question worth proofreading.

It seems to me that it is a nice-to-have. And making it available publicly may not be possible depending on your IRB approval. Now, if you could use your method on other publicly available data that might be interesting.

The question's interesting, but I think it's a question about a specific research topic (which is out of scope) rather than a question about academic procedures/"the business"/etc.

You write your work is:

application of AI models using the data

and the reviewer talked about showcasing improvements of methods.
If your research is on AI models, then the specific data you have should not matter. If anything, your work is probably only valid if it applies broadly to data collected from different places. It's probably worth the effort to clean/preprocess another data set if for no other reason than to validate what you've found.
Some people in your field are especially picky about this because it's very common in your field for people to publish about "improvements" they've made that are not improvements at all but depend strongly on the specific data they are tested on and do not generalize. So, there's a lot of effectively junk work published that cannot be replicated and is not useful to anyone except that it makes it harder to find work that is actually useful. It also may be expected that peer reviewers are able to execute your code to verify your results, and they won't be able to do that without data to process.
If you were applying your models to healthcare data to get answers about healthcare from that specific data, I think you'd have a better argument about using those data alone, but it's still becoming more standard to expect anonymized data to be made public in those cases and you should pursue whether that is a possibility, including obtaining additional approval if necessary.
If you do decide it's not possible, your justification of why you can't release the data should be about why you cannot, not why you don't want to.

"If your research is on AI models, then the specific data you have should not matter." Garbage in, garbage out always applies, of course.

@Anyon Yes of course, by "specific data should not matter" I do not mean "data quality does not matter"; quality is a general characteristic, not a specific one. I mean that if you are trying to say something about "AI models of healthcare data" but your improvement on some characteristic only works with data from Sloan Kettering, you've only shown something about data from Sloan Kettering, not anything about AI models, and it's unlikely that anyone can tell anything about why your changes work with those data without having access to the data.
